# How to get Game Center player name on server-side

Tags: ios, server-side, game-center, server-side-validation

In our multiplayer mobile game we want to use player names from Game Center. Those player names will be shown in public leaderboards, so we want to ensure on our server that Game Center player name is actually belongs to that specific user.

I have found the way to verify player login to Game Center [Setting up third-party server to interact with Game Center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755489/setting-up-third-party-server-to-interact-with-game-center). After verifying Game Center login I have verified playerID.

Is there any way to get player name by this PlayerID from Apple?

Or how can I verify player name I get from client belongs to that user?

P.S. Our server is written in Java so any Java code examples would be appreciated.