# How to authenticate the GKLocalPlayer on my Node.js server

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, authentication, certificate

In [Apple's Doc, generateIdentityVerificationSignatureWithCompletionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKLocalPlayer/generateIdentityVerificationSignatureWithCompletionHandler:), you are to concatenate into a data buffer 4 parameters, one of which being "The timestamp parameter *in Big-Endian UInt-64 format*", and then generate a SHA-1 hash value for verification.

**Has anyone accomplished this successfully in Node.js/Javascript?**  The main issue I am having is that Javascript/Node.js does not seem to have any support 64-bit unsigned big endian integers; it seems to *max out* at 32-bit, unsigned.

PS: I know there the following related questions, but they do not tackle this particular javascript issue.

1. [How to authenticate the GKLocalPlayer on my 'third party
   server'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408729/how-to-authenticate-the-gklocalplayer-on-my-third-party-server/19202727#19202727): the solutions are for ruby, python, and obj-c; all
   having native support for producing the 64-bit BE hex for the
   timestamp.
2. [How to authenticate Game Center User from 3rd party node.js
   server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570700/how-to-authenticate-game-center-user-from-3rd-party-node-js-server%20%22How%20to%20authenticate%20Game%20Center%20User%20from%203rd%20party%20node.js%20server%27): the code relies on the client sending the server a
   timestamp already in the form of a hex string (see
   `json.hexTimestamp`, around ln 22)

Is it even possible to reliably create the hex representation of a 64-bit unsigned big endian ... *in javascript*?  I'm considering executing ruby/python via Node.js as a possible workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is to use ref

```
var ref = require('ref');

var buf = ref.alloc('uint64');
ref.writeUInt64BE(buf, 0, '1401893400733');
```

after that you could use the buffer to update the verifier.