# "invalid ELF header" when using the nodejs "ref" module on AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've just uploaded a zip to AWS Lambda which included the "ref" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ref), which is needed to validate an iOS Game Center authentication token ([How to authenticate Game Center User from 3rd party node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570700/how-to-authenticate-game-center-user-from-3rd-party-node-js-server)).

Unfortunately invoking it results in the "invalid ELF header" error,

```
{
  "errorMessage": "/var/task/node_modules/ref/build/Release/binding.node: invalid ELF header",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Module.load (module.js:356:32)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)",
    "Module.require (module.js:364:17)",
    "require (module.js:380:17)",
    "bindings (/var/task/node_modules/ref/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/ref/lib/ref.js:5:47)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:456:26)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:356:32)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)"
  ]
}
```

This has been developed on a 64bit Macbook Pro running Yosemite which has no problem running the code locally. Googling around for "invalid ELF header" has yielded little to know relevant results and I'm really not sure where to go from here. Would I be better asking this in a node.js area, or is this the relevant area, because it might be an issue with the platform?

Comment: Node modules that include native code must be built on (or for) the target platform.  Rebuild your node modules on the target platform.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This happens when you build on one architecture and then attempt to use the same built addon on a different architecture (or platform in some cases).

According to [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/), addons may have to be compiled against an Amazon Linux image on EC2 in order for the compiled addons to be usable on their Lambda service.

Comment: Great information in the link. I just wanted to add that the EC2 instance to spin should be with name similar to (AMI name: amzn-ami-hvm-2016.03.3.x86_64-gp2) based on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html. In case you don't know which one to create.

Comment: Happens too often while using VMs too, so heads-up, solid answer.

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't apply exactly to your question, but in case anyone stumbles across this when using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, it could be a result of uploading the `node_modules/` directory along with everything else, so you need to force it to ignore the file.

#### `.ebignore`

```
node_modules/
```

Comment: I have been struggling this for a while, thanks for you answer. My initial guess was the EOF line problem because I was doing my development on Windows, and the application runs on AWS Linux container.

Comment: Wow that was exactly what happened to me on Lightsail. Webstorm uploaded even though I didn’t want to

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer to your question that I found on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/gkehsh/lambda_not_working_with_natively_built/):

[SOLVED BY JeffGebhart]
https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/

Then SSH into EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2.

- Install `npm` with `nvm` and `docker` and run

```
docker pull lambci/lambda
```

- run

```
mkdir LambdaFunction
```

- run

```
npm init
```

and initialize everything.

- then you need to be in that folder and run

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda:build-nodejs12.x 
npm install <packages you need>
```

and it will build prover native modules in `node_modules`. Now you can extract all files to your PC or to your AWS.

Answer (score 1):

For those Developers porting JS to TypeScript on Lambda, ensure ALL dependancies are imported, not required:

```
import $ from "cheerio";
```

NOT

```
const $ = require("cheerio");
```

Answer (score 0):

Again, for anyone close to tears on this issue, try individually packaging your functions:

> serverless.ts /.yml

Blockquote

```
  package: {
    individually: true   
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you build on one architecture and then attempt to use the same built addon on a different architecture (or platform in some cases).

You can create/compile the packages with another lambda(same architecture, same language platform) where you compile on temporary file system, zip results and output them to s3. Then go to s3, take the zip and use it.

As I can not comment yet on mscdex, I provided the solution here. I tested this solution for a python dependency I needed to save for a layer and it worked.