# How to load npm modules in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda

I've created several Lambda functions using the web based editor. So far so good. I'd now like to start extending those with modules (such as Q for promises). I can't figure out how to get the modules out to Lambda so they can be consumed by my functions.

I've read through [Using Packages and Native nodejs Modules in AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/) but it seems to involve setting up an EC2 and running Lambda functions from there. There is a mechanism to upload a zip when creating a function but that seems to involve sending up functions developed locally. Since I'm working in the web based editor that seems like a strange workflow.

How can I simply deploy some modules for use in my Lambda functions?

Comment: It is all explained in the docs here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html

Answer (score 308, accepted):

You cannot load NPM modules without uploading a `.zip` file, but you can actually get this process down to two quick command lines.

Here's how:

1. Put your Lambda function file(s) in a separate directory.  This is because you install `npm` packages locally for Lambda and you want to be able to isolate and test what you will upload to Lambda.
2. Install your NPM packages locally with `npm install packageName` while you're in your separate Lambda directory you created in step #1.
3. Make sure your function works when running locally: `node lambdaFunc.js` (you can simply comment out the two `export.handler` lines in your code to adapt your code to run with Node locally).
4. Go to the Lambda's directory and compress the **contents**, make sure **not** to include the directory itself.

   ```
   zip -r lambdaFunc.zip .
   ```
5. If you have the `aws-cli` installed, which I suggest having if you want to make your life easier, you can now enter this command:

   ```
   aws lambda update-function-code --function-name lambdaFunc \
   --zip-file fileb://~/path/to/your/lambdaFunc.zip
   ```

   (no quotes around the lambdaFunc part above in case you wonder as I did)
6. Now you can click *test* in the Lambda console.
7. I suggest adding a short alias for both of the above commands.  Here's what I have in mine for the much longer Lambda update command:

   ```
   alias up="aws lambda update-function-code --function-name lambdaFunc \
   --zip-file fileb://~/path/to/your/lambdaFunc.zip"
   ```

Comment: You may need to explicitly state the region that you are targeting:  


`aws lambda update-function-code --function-name lambdaFunc --region eu-west-1 --zip-file fileb://~/path/to/your/lambdaFunc.zip`

Comment: While it seems like a lot more work, to go through this, it's really a lot better way of building these lambda expressions... thanks a lot!

Comment: yeah it's way less work in the long run and is nice and easily repeatable

Comment: You can also try `recime-cli`(recime.io), this will create the lambda function, install node modules `(including native)`, publish and give you the url that support GET/POST. Although it is designed for bots and has integration support but it also supports CORS therefore you can use it as an agent.

Comment: Make sure it is a `zip` file not a `rar`. Had to go through a lot, before I figured it out.

Comment: I had to use `--zip-file fileb://` versus `--zip-file file://` while using these steps

Comment: But how just to load .node file binary module? I don't have any npm packages, I just need to use single binary file through cont my_module = require('path/to/binary/module/directory) //like index.node
How?

Comment: I usually alias something like `zip -rq $archive * && aws lambda update-function-code --function-name $function --zip-file fileb://$archive`, meaning you could do archive=/tmp/archive.zip function=my_function once, then just call the alias to both zip and deploy at the same time.

Comment: I used this instead of an absolute path (and fileb like McLovin mentions): --zip-file fileb://${PWD}/lambdaFunc.zip

Comment: Make sure you zip *only the contents* of the directory, and that you do it *from the CLI* (using the 'compress' command from Mac's finder [will NOT work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887552/165673)).

Comment: This was super useful.. at least two things were missing to make this work for me... 1) it was `--zip-file fileb:` instead of `file` for me. 2) on MacOS it seems to be with 3 slashes e.g. like `fileb:///Users/wio/Documents`

Comment: That Lamba doesn't have native support for NPM is insane.

Comment: I had a problem with step 2. when I did `yarn install <package.` it used the package.json from the root. So I had to `yarn init` in the directory from step 1. so it would use that

Comment: did you forget to add the npm init step to the new directory or is that not needed here?

Answer (score 68):

A `.zip` file is required in order to include **npm** modules in Lambda. And you really shouldn't be using the Lambda web editor for much of anything- as with any production code, you should be developing locally, committing to git, etc.

#### MY FLOW:

1) My Lambda functions are usually helper utilities for a larger project, so I create a **/aws/lambdas** directory within that to house them.

2) Each individual lambda directory contains an **index.js** file containing the function code, a **package.json** file defining dependencies, and a **/node_modules** subdirectory. (The package.json file is not used by Lambda, it's just so we can locally run the `npm install` command.)

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "my_lambda",
  "dependencies": {
    "svg2png": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

3) I .gitignore all node_modules directories and .zip files so that the files generated from npm installs and zipping won't clutter our repo.

**.gitignore:**

```
# Ignore node_modules
**/node_modules

# Ignore any zip files
*.zip
```

4) I run `npm install` from within the directory to install modules, and develop/test the function locally.

5) I .zip the lambda directory and upload it via the console.

(**IMPORTANT:** Do not use Mac's 'compress' utility from Finder to zip the file! You must run zip from the CLI from within the root of the directory- see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887552/165673))

```
zip -r ../yourfilename.zip *
```

---

**NOTE:**

You might run into problems if you install the node modules locally on your Mac, as some platform-specific modules may fail when deployed to Lambda's Linux-based environment. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29994851/165673)

The solution is to compile the modules on an EC2 instance launched from the AMI that corresponds with the Lambda Node.js runtime you're using (See this list of [Lambda runtimes and their respective AMIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html)).

---

See also [AWS Lambda Deployment Package in Node.js - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html)

Answer (score 56):

You can now use Lambda Layers for this matters. Simply add a layer containing the package you need and it will run perfectly.

Follow this post: [NodeJS Runtime Environment with AWS Lambda Layers](https://medium.com/@anjanava.biswas/nodejs-runtime-environment-with-aws-lambda-layers-f3914613e20e)

Comment: Didn't know about layers until this very moment. Thank you Eldad!

Comment: Why not use AWS Toolkit? Seems like that's trying to take over "all of this"? (there's some frustrating fragmentation in docs about how to do all this... a) web-based editor b) manual .zip uploads c) SAM d) Layers now e) AWS Toolkit... yikes as dev trying to navigate)

Answer (score 11):

Hope this helps, with Serverless framework you can do something like this:

1. Add these things in your `serverless.yml` file:

```
    plugins:
      - serverless-webpack
    custom:
      webpackIncludeModules:
        forceInclude:
          - <your package name> (for example: node-fetch)
```

2. Then create your Lambda function, deploy it by `serverless deploy`, the package that included in serverless.yml will be there for you.

For more information about serverless: [Setting Up Serverless Framework With AWS](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/quick-start/)

Comment: you need first to install it `serverless plugin install --name pluginName`

Answer (score 9):

After fiddling around with parcel for a few hours, I found that it seems to make some assumptions about running in a browser (even if I tell it to use `engine: node`).

Instead:

---

#### esbuild

Much easier, and also faster, is **esbuild**!

Simply run `npm add --save-dev esbuild`, and add these scripts to your `package.json`:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild --bundle --minify --platform=node --target=node12 --outdir=build main.js",
    "export": "cd build && zip main.js.zip main.js"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "esbuild": "^0.11.19",
    ...
  }
}
```

This allowed me to use the `aws-sdk` while still getting tree-shaking and minifying, while still being able to install other dependencies such as jest and eslint without having to package the whole `node_modules` folder.

To build a package within CI, simply:
`npm ci && npm run build && npm run export`

The file `build/main.js.zip` will then contain everything you need!

Comment: I nearly overlooked this solution because of the initial 'parcel' paragraph that is not really relevant, but otherwise this solution is great; really simple and effective.

Comment: This won't work with sharp library which has hardcoded reference sharp lib: require(`../build/Release/sharp-${platformAndArch}.node`); With enabled bundling, main.js is trying to access this file from relative path ../build/Release

Answer (score 7):

Also in the many IDEs now, ex: VSC, you can install an extension for AWS and simply click upload from there, no effort of typing all those commands + region.

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: AWS VS Code extension can be found [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-toolkit-vscode)

Comment: I cannot see any relation to the NPM package like in the question

Answer (score 2):

npm module has to be bundeled inside your nodejs package and upload to AWS Lambda Layers as zip, then you would need to refer to your module/js as below and use available methods from it.

`const mymodule = require('/opt/nodejs/MyLogger');`

Answer (score 2):

Deploying your lambda function using AWS CDK might be a good choice if you have multiple AWS resources to manage. It's an IaC tool that deploys AWS resources and uses CloudFormation. To set up CDK see [Getting started with the AWS CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/getting_started.html).

Once you have CDK set up, you can create a Function construct and use its [`lambda.Code.fromAsset`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda-readme.html#bundling-asset-code) to easily bundle up your source code, including `node_modules`, and use it as the code for the Function.

```js
import * as lambda from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import * as path from "path";

export class MyStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {

    const lambdaFunc = new lambda.Function(this, "lambdaFunc", {
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "project-containing-node-modules")),
      ...
    });

  }
}
```

Then use `cdk deploy` to deploy it to your AWS account.

[Lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda-readme.html#layers) are also supported in CDK if you are using the same node_modules across multiple Lambdas and don't want to upload duplicate dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old-ish question, but it helped lead me to a really easy way of adding new Lambda dependencies to an Alexa skill.

Like JohnAllen's answer, you need to create a folder on your local machine, title it whatever you want (it's arbitrary):

```
mkdir lambdaFunc
cd lambdaFunc
```

Once in your folder, use `npm` to install the necessary package. For me, I needed to parse ISO8601 durations (my command was `npm install iso8601-duration`):

```
npm install <your-package-here>
```

Once installed, back out of that directory, and zip it. Open up your Alexa Skill in the Alexa Skill developer console, then select the "Import Code" option. From here, you'll upload your .zip file, and select all the code:

[image: Import Lambda Code in Alexa Skill Developer Console]

[image: Select all code in .zip file]

That's it! Then you can just import the code, like I did:

```
const DateConverter = require('iso8601-duration');
```

Answer (score 1):

The AWS CDK has a nice solution for this. There is a lambda construct called  [NodejsFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html). It uses esbuild to package your code with its dependencies into a single asset which is uploaded as a zip when you 'deploy' the application.

You basically just have to give a path to the file that contains your handler function as follows:

```
const { Stack } = require('aws-cdk-lib');
const lambdaNodeJs = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs');
const path = require("path");

class CdkStack extends Stack {
    constructor(scope, id, props) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const myLambda = new lambdaNodeJs.NodejsFunction(this, "my-lambda-id", {
            functionName: 'my-function-name',
            entry: path.join(path.join(__dirname, '/../../path/to/handler.js')),
            handler: 'handler-function-name'
            // rest of the config.
        });
    }
}
```

Make sure that you have the [esbuild](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild) as a dependency in the package.json file for the lambda code and you are good to go.