# stopDBCluster (Aurora) not a function aws-sdk javascript lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

Inside a newly created lambda function (with all the permissions set up), I have:

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");

aws.config.apiVersions = {
  rds: '2014-10-31'
};

const rds = new aws.RDS();
```

When I call `rds.describeDBClusters({DBClusterIdentifier: 'mycluster'})`, everything works as expected.

When I call `rds.stopDBCluster({DBClusterIdentifier: 'mycluster'})`, I get

`TypeError: rds.stopDBCluster is not a function`.

In the api docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDS.html
There is documented the `stopDBCluster` function.  I also notice that if I look at the docs for an earlier version of the API, the `stopDBCluster` function is not there.

Has anybody else ran into this?  Even though I am calling out the most recent api in the sdk config, is it possible that the function is still using an older one?

- Runtime for lambda = `Node 8.10`
- Permissions seems to be good since the describe function works and this is a runtime reference error anyhow.
- Database is Aurora with Postgres(10 I think)
- Same issue if I pass the api version into the RDS constructor

Comment: Can you compare the SDK versions on local and in lambda.Issue might be happening because of version mismatch as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53902879/4326922

Answer (score 0):

This must be a bug with the aws-sdk on lambda.  When I run all the same code locally with permissions, after doing an npm install of aws-sdk, everything works fine.