# Amazon AWS Lambda functions having Repository....?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

the lambda functions having Repository if yes how to check the Repository details how it will be deployed if no Repository.

Answer (score 0):

Theres no "hidden" or "shared" repository that can be used between different lambda functions, every file you need should be uploaded in the zip file you upload.

Read a more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34439125/10770370).

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions do not have repositories. You can create a deployment package yourself or write your code directly in the Lambda console, in which case the console creates the deployment package for you and uploads it, creating your Lambda function.

- If your custom code requires only the AWS SDK library, then you can use the inline editor in the AWS Lambda console. Using the console, you can edit and upload your code to AWS Lambda. The console will zip up your code with the relevant configuration information into a deployment package that the Lambda service can run.
  You can also test your code in the console by manually invoking it using sample event data.
- In the case of the deployment package, you may either upload it directly or upload the .zip file first to an Amazon S3 bucket in the same AWS region where you want to create the Lambda function, and then specify the bucket name and object key name when you create the Lambda function using the console or the AWS CLI