# Is dynamodb-geo supported in lambda running Node?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, geohashing

I'm trying to create a simple application following this [article](https://read.acloud.guru/location-based-search-results-with-dynamodb-and-geohash-267727e5d54f), but I cannot get my Node Lambda function to find the dynamodb-geo package.

Here is what I have:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddbGeo = require('dynamodb-geo');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  // Rest of the code here
};
```

And the error Lambda throws is:

> START RequestId: 5d40d132-040f-447d-bd76-35c4cec0236a Version: $LATEST
>   2019-10-05T10:04:24.719Z  undefined   ERROR   Uncaught
>   Exception {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error:
>   Cannot find module
>   'dynamodb-geo'","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot
>   find module 'dynamodb-geo'","    at _loadUserApp
>   (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)","    at
>   Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)","
>   at Object. (/var/runtime/index.js:45:30)","    at
>   Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)","    at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)","    at Module.load
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)","    at tryModuleLoad
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)","    at Function.Module._load
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)","    at
>   Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)","
>   at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)"]} END RequestId:
>   5d40d132-040f-447d-bd76-35c4cec0236a REPORT RequestId:
>   5d40d132-040f-447d-bd76-35c4cec0236a  Duration: 1146.75 ms    Billed
>   Duration: 1200 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 35 MB   Unknown
>   application error occurred Runtime.ImportModuleError

Any clue on what could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only included package on AWS Lambda is the aws-sdk package. Everything else (except standard node packages) needs to be packaged and uploaded with your code.

There are many tools to achieve this:

- the [AWS cli](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/cli/) (see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437900...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437900/how-to-load-npm-modules-in-aws-lambda))
- the [Serverless framework](https://serverless.com)
- [AWS Amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/)
- [AWS CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the package?

Using npm or yarn: `npm install --save dynamodb-geo` or `yarn add dynamodb-geo`.

Doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-geo

Comment: Thank you for your sugestion. I'm running this project in a serverless environment. I cannot just install the package. You guided my investigation though, and I found out that actually AWS does not include that package in its runtime, and if I want to use it I need to upload it as part of the code.

Comment: yes, you were missing the packages in your lambda. I suggest using serverless framework for deployment, so you can add dependecies easier https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Lambda layer](https://medium.com/@anjanava.biswas/nodejs-runtime-environment-with-aws-lambda-layers-f3914613e20e) in order to easily import external packages: