# How do I use node modules on the Alexa Developer Console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, module, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to make an Alexa skill which uses a Node.JS API using a module, usually installed via npm. However, I can't upload the node modules as there is no upload button. I can't just simply use npm install as there is no console. How would I do this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34439125/10980926) help?

Comment: See, this would be super helpful except I'm just straight up using https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/. I have no idea how to use AWS or the sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the follow-up questions, you say you're using straight developer.amazon.com and not messing with AWS.

When you're using the Alexa Hosted feature and the code editor in the Alexa developer console, you'll edit your package.json in the code editor to make the module a dependency and the package should get loaded automatically when you save and deploy your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a serverless aws function in your aws account. please follow the below link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-nodejs.html

When your Lambda function is created, you will generate an ARN URL: You need to add an ARN url in the Alexa Developer Console under the endpoint section.

https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?openid.pape.preferred_auth_policies=Singlefactor&clientContext=131-8111090-7713609&openid.pape.max_auth_age=7200&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.amazon.com%2Falexa%2Fconsole%2Fask&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=amzn_dante_us&openid.mode=checkid_setup&marketPlaceId=ATVPDKIKX0DER&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&

When your Alexa Developer Console & AWS Lambda function is connected, you need to create a zip for your project folder and upload a zip in your lambda function. Once the zip is uploaded, you will be able to do a skill test from Alexa Developer Console.