# MariaSql in NodeJs and AWS Lambda - "Module did not Self-Register

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda, mariasql

I'm creating an AWS lambda function with NodeJS which will call to an AWS RDS instance. To do this I'm using the 'MariaSql' module. The function executes perfectly from my local command line, but after zipping the file and uploading it to Lambda, I receive this error:

```
"errorMessage": "Module did not self-register.",
"errorType": "Error",
"stackTrace": [
"Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:434:18)",
"Module.load (module.js:343:32)",
"Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)",
"Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
"require (internal/module.js:12:17)",
"Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mariasql/lib/Client.js:13:11)",
"Module._compile (module.js:409:26)",
"Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)",
"Module.load (module.js:343:32)"
]
```

I have built the program in EC2 and included an `init: npm install` in the package.json in the hopes that the module would reigster/be created. I've also tried deleting and re-installing `node_modules` as well as trying `npm rebuild` to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [aws - "Unable to import module 'process': /var/task/numpy/core/multiarray.so: invalid ELF header"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881240/aws-unable-to-import-module-process-var-task-numpy-core-multiarray-so-in)

Comment: @KarenB That's what I had hoped! I spun up a linux EC2 instance and created the entire project from scratch in that environment. Tried zipping it up (both on the EC2 instance and downloaded onto my local storage) but still receive the same error