# aws - Cannot import module in python 2.7 : /var/task/Crypto/Util/_counter.so: invalid ELF header

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services

Is there a solution that does not require a virtaulenv, as per the fix in the answer below?

[aws - "Unable to import module 'process': /var/task/numpy/core/multiarray.so: invalid ELF header"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881240/aws-unable-to-import-module-process-var-task-numpy-core-multiarray-so-in)