# AWS Elastic Beanstalk invalid binary packages

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am working on migrating a project from Heroku to AWS.  I keep getting an error after deployment saying: 'invalid ELF header'.  I have found posts with similar issues when using AWS Lambda, but I do not understand why I would have an issue with binary packages in Elastic Beanstalk.

Doesn't Elastic Beanstalk provide a configured environment to run my code similar to Docker?  I feel like this problem must be more complex as I cannot find anyone else with this issue in Elastic Beanstalk.

Here is the exact error I am getting:

```
Error: /var/app/current/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:18)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! beer@0.1.0 start: `node server/server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the beer@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/.npm/_logs/2019-04-15T00_54_06_983Z-debug.log
```

I am working on a Mac, my code contains both client and server code written in React, node.js, and SQL. I am uploading my code via a ZIP file containing multiple folders, including `node_modules/`.

Comment: And do you have multiple `node_modules/` folders, e.g. one for your front-end and another for your back-end?

Comment: @Chris I only have one node_modules folder, but there are many sub-folders inside this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some libraries are sensitive to the operating system and / or CPU architecture on which they are built. This is especially true of modules implemented in low-level languages, or that link to system libraries. In this case, you appear to be using [`bcrypt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) which is [largely written in C++](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js).

This is one reason that the zip file you upload to Elastic Beanstalk shouldn't include your `node_modules/` folder (or anything else that Git is ignoring). The easiest way to create a zip for uploading to Elastic Beanstalk is [probably to use `git archive`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html#using-features.deployment.source.git):

```
 git archive -v -o myapp.zip --format=zip HEAD
```

This will respect your ignores, whereas [manually zipping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html#using-features.deployment.source.commandline) will include them.

Your archive should include `package.json` and `package-lock.json` in its root. Elastic Beanstalk [will install its own `node_modules/` from these files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-packagejson.html) if they are present. This should ensure that all libraries are compatible with its operating system.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this looks like it will fix my problem.  Do you happen to know why Heroku ignores node_modules when I upload my code there?

Comment: It's not that it's _ignoring_ that directory. It's that some modules are sensitive to the operating system and / or CPU architecture on which they are built. This is especially true for modules written in low-level languages like C or linking to system libraries. I suspect you're using [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) which is [largely written in C++](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js). I'll clarify my answer.