# Heroku can't load canvas for discord.js bot, says "invalid ELF header"

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, canvas, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot using node js and it works perfectly when run on VSC. However, it gives this error when I try to run it on heroku with github. Can someone please let me know what this error means and how to fix it? It looks like theres something wrong with loading canvas. I'm very new to this btw...

````
2021-07-01T18:23:12.543498+00:00 app[worker.1]:   return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
2021-07-01T18:23:12.543499+00:00 app[worker.1]:                  ^
2021-07-01T18:23:12.543499+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2021-07-01T18:23:12.543499+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: /app/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node: invalid ELF header
2021-07-01T18:23:12.543500+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:18)
2021-07-01T18:23:12.543500+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
2021-07-01T18:23:12.543500+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
2021-07-01T18:23:12.543501+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
2021-07-01T18:23:12.543501+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
2021-07-01T18:23:12.543501+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
2021-07-01T18:23:12.543502+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
2021-07-01T18:23:12.543502+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2021-07-01T18:23:12.543502+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
2021-07-01T18:23:12.543503+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
2021-07-01T18:23:20.479045+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error waiting for network: Resource temporarily unavailable```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["invalid ELF header" when using the nodejs "ref" module on AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994411/invalid-elf-header-when-using-the-nodejs-ref-module-on-aws-lambda). Don't copy the node_modules from one system to another, it can break easily.